# python write file .txt isn't saving output correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I have a series of urls in a .txt I want to print the python changes I made to a new .txt

My URLS.txt

```
    http://www.live.com
    http://www.twitter. com
    http://www.youtube.com
```

After I make the changes the terminal output is print(new_list)

```
    ['http://www.live.com'],
    ['http://www.twitter.com'],
    ['http://www.youtube.com'],
```

Then when I write to the new .txt the only thing that is written is

```
    ['http://www.youtube.com'],
```

The code I used to write to the new text is as follows

```
    with open("listurls.txt", "w") as f:
            f.writelines(new_list)
```

new_list is a str

Is there a reason I can't get each line to print in my .txt file?

Whole code is below, I know it's a bit long winded but it's for an exercise

```
with open ("testurls.txt", "r") as txt_file:            
for urls in txt_file:                               
    data = urls                                     
    #print(data)                                   
    def remove(data):                               
       return data.replace(" ", "")                  
    #print (remove(data))                           
    links = (remove(data))                          
    #print(links)                                   
    def Convert(string):                            
        li = list(string.split(" "))                
        return li
    str1 = links                                    
    #print(Convert(str1))                           
    list_urls = (Convert(str1))                     
    #print(list_urls)                               
    stripped = [s.rstrip('\n') for s in list_urls]  
    #print (stripped)                               
    value = stripped                                
    for lists in value:                             
        new_list = ("['" + lists + "'],")           
        print(new_list)                            
        with open("listurls.txt", "w") as f:
            f.writelines(new_list)
            #I MADE IT THIS FAR
```

Comment: Easiest may be to open the file first and _keep it open_ while you write all rows. Right now you're opening and overwriting it for each row (mode 'w' overwrites the old content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your file in append mode. Use this code to write in file

```
with open("listurls", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(new_list)
```

Comment: I appreciate it. This was exactly what I was looking for. I must have missed that in that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way you write the list to the file. Actually, you overwrite the file for each list element in this piece of the code:

```
for lists in value:                             
        new_list = ("['" + lists + "'],")           
        print(new_list)                            
        with open("listurls.txt", "w") as f:   # <<--- here is the problem
            f.writelines(new_list)
```

**The easiest way** to correct it is to change the file opening mode from writing and overwriting (`"w"` in the `open` function), to creating if missing and appending (`"a"`).

However, **the proper way** would be to open the file once and write the whole list to it instead of recreating the file each time.

Let's correct it putting `for` in the `with` context manager:

```
    with open("listurls.txt", "w") as f:
        for lists in value:                             
            new_list = ("['" + lists + "'],")           
            print(new_list)                            
            f.writelines(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

writelines() is not appending new_list to listurls.txt. What it is doing is :-

```
listurls = ['http://www.live.com'],
```

in the first iteration.

In the next iteration,

```
listurls = ['http://www.twitter.com'],
```

instead of

```
listurls = ['http://www.live.com'],
           ['http://www.twitter.com'],
```

To resolve this issue, open listurls in append mode, and not write mode.

```
with open("listurls.txt", "w+") as f:
            f.writelines(new_list)
```

or

```
with open("listurls.txt", "a+") as f:
            f.writelines(new_list)
```

or

```
with open("listurls.txt", "a") as f:
            f.writelines(new_list)
```