# How to save model output/predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a model. Now I want to export it's output which is type (str). How I can I save it's output results in a dataframe or any other form that I can use for future purpose.

```
gf = df['findings'].astype(str) 
preprocess_text = gf.str.strip().replace("\n","") 
t5_prepared_Text = "summarize: "+preprocess_text print ("original text preprocessed: \n", preprocess_text) 
tokenized_text = tokenizer.encode(str(t5_prepared_Text, return_tensors="pt").to(device) 
# summmarize 
summary_ids = model.generate(tokenized_text, num_beams=4, no_repeat_ngram_size=2, min_length=30, max_length=100, early_stopping=True) 
output = tokenizer.decode(summary_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True) print ("\n\nSummarized text: \n"
```

Output of the model

```
0     summarize: There is XXXX increased opacity wit...
1     summarize: There is XXXX increased opacity wit...
2     summarize: There is XXXX increased opacity wit...
3     summarize: Interstitial markings are diffusely...
4     summarize: Interstitial markings are diffusely...
5                                        summarize: nan
6                                        summarize: nan
Name: findings, dtype: object:
```

So far I have tried like this

```
prediction = pd.DataFrame([text]).to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

But it saves all these rows in just one cell of the csv (first cell) and all in half form like below.

```
0     summarize: There is XXXX increased opacity wit...
1     summarize: There is XXXX increased opacity wit...
2     summarize: There is XXXX increased opacity wit...
3     summarize: Interstitial markings are diffusely...
4     summarize: Interstitial markings are diffusely...
5                                        summarize: nan
6                                        summarize: nan
Name: findings, dtype: object:
```

Comment: Since from your sample, the output doesn't lend itself to a tabular structure, you can save the output as a text file

Comment: How to save it as txt?

Comment: see [python write file .txt isn't saving output correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890914/python-write-file-txt-isnt-saving-output-correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace this

```
prediction = pd.DataFrame([text]).to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

With this

```
prediction = pd.DataFrame([text]).to_csv('prediction.csv', sep=";")
```